# A British girl wakes in pre-Arthurian world as future mother of Arthur

Tags: story-identification, arthurian

She wakes up in the wintertime and travels through the mythical world accompanied by season-of-year related animals: wolf, then black panther.
Story features at least two Celtic demi-gods and their mother, a snake-woman, weaving the fabric of reality.

Probably mid 80s.

Edit in response to comments below:

- I read it in early nineties, I believe, in Polish translation. 80s are a kinda wild guess. The author was female, I am almost sure.

Some more random elements:

- One of landmarks was called Randolph's Ditch -- one of the few common elements connecting our reality with the mythical one.
- The dark-haired demi-god was her chosen partner, the blond one was
  chasing and even tried to rape her (unsucessfully, as the magic plant
  hidden in her clothes made him, ekhm, unable).
- The whole story starts in the winter, and as the summer arrives her
  familiar changes -- or is replaced. Also, the blond-haired
  character prevails over the dark one, only to be killed by a wild hog
  at the end of summer.
- The final (?) scene is her giving birth to Arthur.

This is all I can recall, sorry.

Comment: A good start but we're going to need some more details. Try and think of any other plot elements or settings.

Comment: Did you read it in the mid 80s, or do you think it was published in the mid 80s?